# Can't printf ASCII value for scanf_s value of variable

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Trying to get the user-input value for a character, then display that as the ASCII integer number. It doesn't want to do it--as I keep getting a blank output. However, if I manually assign a character letter to `let` it works fine.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define eps 8.85e-12

int main() {

   int x = 1, y = 2, z;
   float p = 2.5, q = 4.8;
   double a = 2.5e-9, b;
   char let;

   z = 2 * y;
   printf(" x/(y+z) = %.1f \n", (float)x/(y + z));

   printf(" Get an alphabet ");
   scanf_s("%c", &let);
   printf("ASCII value of the alphabet is %d\n", let);

   printf("Insert value of b :");
   scanf_s("%lf", &b);
   printf("value of eps/(a*b)= %8.2e\n", eps / (a*b));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s` takes an extra length parameter for `%c`, `%s`, and `%[]` format specifiers. Add another argument with the value 1.

Comment: [Link to documentation for `scanf_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), pay particular attention to the types that require specified length parameters also be passed.

Comment: The only reason I'm using `scanf_s` is because of VS'13.

Comment: Note: Suspect you then want `eps / ((a-'0')*b)`.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx):

> Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` **require** the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type `c`, `C`, `s`, `S`, or string control sets that are enclosed in `[]`. **The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.**

So what you need is:

```
scanf_s("%c", &let, sizeof(let));
```

although, as with most of these safe functions, they're no safer than the "unsafe" ones if you know what you're doing.

Note I'm not including the *truly* unsafe variants like `gets(str)` or `scanf ("%s",str)` but those where you *know and control* how much input you'll consume are just fine.